# Popover presentation in iOS 9

Tags: ipad, swift2

I want to Display a viewController in Popover in iPad . But this line
 self.poc = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sec) deprected in iOS 9

```
let sec:PopView=PopView(nibName:"PopView",bundle:nil)
        self.poc = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sec)
        poc!.delegate=self
        self.poc!.presentPopoverFromRect( CGRect(x: 150, y: 222, width: 50, height: 30), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, animated: true)
```

Comment: where is the above code, in a segue preparation? and what is the presenter vc (what are sec and poc)... try to put more description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UIPopoverPresentationController :

```
let sec = UIViewController(nibName:"PopView",bundle:nil)
sec.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

if let secPopoverPresentationController = sec.popoverPresentationController{
    secPopoverPresentationController.sourceView = yourSourceView
    secPopoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.Any]
    //Optionally configure other things like sourceRect , delegate ...
}

presentViewController(sec, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps.